# Azure Data Factory is not able to run the SQL Server Stored Procedure despite correct input parameters

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am running a ADF pipeline where output of previous activities are input to another activity (which is a SQL Server SP).
Below is the input that I am getting from ADF pipeline to the SP. Note that there are two inputs viz `@CheckColumn` and `@json`

```
{
"storedProcedureName": "<name of the SP to be executed>",
"storedProcedureParameters": {
    "CheckColumn": {
        "value": "AEDAT",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "json": {
        "value": [
            {
                "AEDAT": "20211112"
            },
            {
                "AEDAT": "20211112"
            },
            {
                "AEDAT": "20211112"
            }
        ],
        "type": "String"
    }

 }
```

When I am running the SP activity, I am getting an error as follows:

```
Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 13609. Error Message: JSON text is not 
properly formatted. Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0.
```

When I am running the SP as stand alone using the above key values (i.e. `CheckColumn` and `json`except `"type":"String"`), it is running fine. In the SP the important part is as follow:

```
SELECT @LastUpdatedValue = CASE WHEN @incremental_type = 'Datetime' 
                                THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,MAX(CAST(JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.'+ '' + @CheckColumn + '') AS datetime)),120),@max_date_time)
                                ELSE MAX(JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.' + '' + @CheckColumn + '')) 
                                END 
                                FROM OPENJSON(@json) AS j;
```

Here `@CheckColumn` is the column name that are being passed as parameter (Please refer to the above string as input) and `@json` is the json string.

I am clueless on why this is not happening from ADF?

Comment: I guess if you are passing a string that looks like JSON, you need to put it in quotes, i.e. `"[.... ]"`

Comment: Did you try `json` function in Azure Data Factory `pipeline expression` `@json({...})`?

Comment: I have tried but didn't work. However what I ended up using is `@concat('{"value":[',join(variables('AppendJson'), ','),']}')` to pass the json as per desired format.